# How to compare two sharepoint field values equal the condition should be execute?

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, content-type

In sharepoint i have one list, list name FieldMapping.It contains 3 fields .
For example in my list i given name like Sqlfields,contractfields and InputType.
this field contains some values.In separate i was stored this field values like this

```
List<string> listOfsqlfields = new List<string>();
List<string> listOfLockfield = new List<string>();
foreach (SPListItem items in Inputtype)
{

    sqlfields = items["Title"].ToString();

   lockfields = items["InputType"].ToString();

   listOfsqlfields.Add(sqlfields);
   listOfLockfield.Add(lockfields );
}
```

I want to compare sqlfields and lockfields 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

See this image here I want to compare SQLFields(here SQLFields are Contenttype fields) and InputType. If InputType is lock in form user not able to edit the column.

```
foreach (SPField field in oCType.Fields)
  {

 FormField formField = new FormField();
 formField.ListId = olist.ID;
 formField.FieldName = field.InternalName;
 formField.ID = string.Format("Field_{0}",
 field.InternalName); // Unique Id to identify control on page 
  // formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;

  //if (Lockfield == "Lock")
   //{

if (listOfsqlfields.Contains(formField.FieldName) != listOfLockfield.Contains(Lockfield))
{
formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
}
else
{
  formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
}       
}
```

For example in that image `txtCan_ReqNum` is lock while looping `field.InternalName` is `txtCan_ReqNum` then I want to execute this condition without hard coding the column name.

```
formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Display;
```

For example in that `image PO_Num` is UnLock while looping `field.InternalName` is `PO_Num` then I want to execute this condition.

```
formField.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dictionary` instead of list

```
Dictionary<string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (SPListItem items in Inputtype) {
    mappings.Add(items["Title"].ToString(),items["InputType"].ToString());
}
```

Next inside the loop

```
foreach (SPField field in oCType.Fields){
   string lock = mappings[field.FieldName];

   //Use lock variable to use in the logic
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Amal. I tried like this It was working fine.

Comment: be careful with the `.ToString()` if you have no value in your field you have a NULL value, so you will got a **NullReferenceException**; You should use : `Convert.ToString(items["FieldName"])`